# How to install SSDT or BIDS into existing Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2012

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server 2012, now I am trying to download SSDT or BIDS for Visual Studio 2010 but not getting that one. I downloaded `SSDTBI_VS2012_x86.exe`.

It will support or not, help me..

Comment: What you downloaded is the SSDT for Visual Studio **2012** - you nee to get the one for Visual Studio **2010** ....

Comment: i need to work with SSRS but in my VS2010 which i am using now have't SSDT or BIDS, how to install SSDT

Comment: Download [SSDT for Visual Studio 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj650014.aspx) and install it ....

Comment: here ..Download SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2010- link is not working

Comment: SQL Server Data Tools for VS 2010 is not finding in [ms site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BIDS changed to Sql Server Data tools so just dowloaded [VS2012](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843)